# form select in Spring MVC with fmt

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

I have this property in a form

```
<select id="deviceSubStatesId" name="deviceSubStatusKey">
    <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
    <c:forEach items="${deviceSubStates}" var="status">                                                 
        <option value="${status.key}"><fmt:message key="${status.key}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

in the Form ojbect I have a String property named `cancelledSubStatusKey` but the value in the controller is NULL !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC binds form data to the model object based on the field names. If you want to bind field with name `cancelledSubStatusKey` then you should modify `name` attribute of the `<select>` tag to match this name:

```
<select id="deviceSubStatesId" name="cancelledSubStatusKey">
```